# Variational Method / Proof using bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I want to prove that the expectation value of the Hamiltonian $H$ in a state $\Psi$ is an upper bound to the ground state energy.

The proof in my textbook makes sense but does it using integrals. So I tried to do it using bra-ket notation because it just seems a lot more aesthetic that way.

My attempt was this:

> Consider a Hamiltonian $H$ with a complete set of orthonormal eigenfunctions $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3, ...,$ with associated eigenvalues $E_1, E_2, E_3, ..., $ such that $E_1 \leq E_2 \leq E_3 \leq ...$.
>
> Then any state of the system $\Psi$ can be expanded as a linearly combinations of the eigenfunctions, so $\Psi = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \phi_n$.
>
> Now consider the expectation value of the Hamiltonian in the state $\Phi$:
>
> $$\begin{align} I &= \frac{<\Psi | H|\Psi>}{<\Psi | \Psi>} \\ & = \frac{<\sum_n c_n \phi_n | H | \sum_m c_m \phi_m >}{<\sum_n c_n \phi_n | \sum_m c_m \phi_m>} \\ & = \frac{\sum_{n,m} c_n^* c_m<\phi_n|H|\phi_m>}{\sum_{n, m} c_n^* c_m <\phi_n | \phi_m>}\end{align}$$
>
> and then since the eigenfunctions are orthonormal, $I = \frac{\sum_n |c_n|^2 E_n}{\sum_n |c_n|^2}$. From here it is easy.

But is what I've done so far ok? Am I missing anything?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems right to me.

Comment: @ManvendraSomvanshi yayyyy!!

Comment: The expression you got is the definition of weighted average, which is  expectation value in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Why the downvote? What’s wrong with this post?